# Adicionar links em palavras de um texto

Tags: javascript, html

Em uma página em html como fazer para as palavras do texto serem convertidas em links? para que ao clicar em determinada palavra, abrir a página google translate com a tradução da palavra.

Por exemplo, nesta frase:

```
"The universe is to everyone"
```

Se o usuário clicar me `"The"` vai abrir o link

`https://translate.google.com/m/translate?ie=UTF8&sl=pt-BR&tl=en&q=#en/pt/The`

Se clicar em `universe` abre

`https://translate.google.com/m/translate?ie=UTF8&sl=pt-BR&tl=en&q=#en/pt/universe`

Comment: Você que criar um link para todas as palavras do texto: "The", "universe", "is", "to", "everyone"?.. se não, qual o critério a ser adotado?

Comment: E se tiver um ponto, uma vírgula... por isso seria preciso definir um critério e aplicar apenas o link a palavras à partir de uma lista de palavras pré-determinadas.

Comment: @sam isso, para todas as palavras separadamente, tem que ver também que deve desconsiderar números e pontuação.  

Vou testar as respostas propostas aqui

Comment: Só serve palavra por palavra? Fiz um exemplo que pode ser o que for selecionado, inclusive todo o texto,

Comment: Show Léo, é interessante esta opção também, obrigado!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Explicação:

#### criarLink

1. Recebe uma palavra e inseri em um [Templete String](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/template_strings) de uma tag a

#### criarArrayDeLinks

1. Pega o texto do elemento usando [textContent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent)
2. Realiza uma separação da string por espaço, transformando a um array usando o [.split()](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split)
3. Filtra o array removendo posições vazias ou quebra de linha com [.filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filtro)
4. Mapeia o nosso array de palavras para um array de tags usando o metodo **criarLink** usando o prototype [.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

#### criarLinksEmElementos

1. Crio um array chamado tags que recebera nossos links e elementos filhos no formato string
2. Recebe o elemento pai verficando se o [nodeType](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/nodeType) é 3(Text)
3. Se seu nodeType **NÃO** for 3(Text) ele verifica se tem elementos filho e se os mesmos são do tipo 3(Text) se não ele cria uma [recursividade](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7065120/calling-a-javascript-function-recursively) chamando a si mesmo.
4. Caso o nodeType seja 3(Text) chamo a função **criarArrayDeLinks** que me retorna um array
5. Realizo a desestruturação do array usando o [spread operator da es6](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator) para atribui-lo ao array tags diretamente.
6. Verifico se o array contem algo
7. Se conter seu limpo o elemento pai com o [innerHTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML)
8. Junto o array em uma string separando por espaço usando o [.join](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join)
9. Por fim atribuo a string na div novamente usando o [innerHTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML) para converter o texto em html

#### criarTextoClicavel

1. Seleciona o devido elemento com [querySelector](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector)
2. Chamo a função **criarLinksEmElementos** passando o resultado obtido no passo anterior

```js
var criarLink = t => `<a target="_blank" href="https://translate.google.com/m/translate?ie=UTF8&sl=pt-BR&tl=en&q=#en/pt/${t}">${t}</a>`

var criarArrayDeLinks = e => e.textContent.split(' ').filter(i => i !== '' && i !== '\n').map(i => criarLink(i));

function criarLinksEmElementos(pai) {
  const tags = [];

  if (pai.nodeType == 3 && pai.textContent.trim()) { 
    tags.push(...criarArrayDeLinks(e));
  } else {          
    pai.childNodes
       .forEach(
          e => {         
            if (e.nodeType == 3 && e.textContent.trim()) { 
              tags.push(...criarArrayDeLinks(e));
            } else {          
              tags.push(criarLinksEmElementos(e).outerHTML);
            }
        });
  }
  
  if (tags.length) {    
    pai.innerHTML = tags.join(' ');    
  }

  return pai;  
}

function criarTextoClicavel(seletor) {  
  const div = document.querySelector(seletor);
  criarLinksEmElementos(div);
}

criarTextoClicavel('#texto-clicavel');
```

```css
/* caso queria remover o efeito do link */
a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<div id="texto-clicavel">
  <p>
    The universe is to everyone
  </p>
  <p>
    The <b>universe</b> is to <i>everyone</i>
  </p>
</div>
```

Comment: Achei até que seria negativado pela pergunta, mas sua resposta está massa, vou testar.  Muito obrigado!

Comment: Marcos, nesse caso ele não retorna o html no layout que estava antes, ou seja, remove os parágrafos e todas tags html, deixando o texto sem nenhuma formatação de layout

Comment: Acredito que teria que considerar pelo menos os parágrafos

Comment: @MiguelSilva não sei se ainda vai ajudar mas esta ai o que tinha comentado.

Comment: Marcos, quando uma palavra inicia por aspas (") ela não recebe o link corretamente, até tentei resolver, mas não consegui, sabe como resolver?

Comment: Muito boa explicação.

Answer (score 2):

Uma solução é:

- dividir o texto em palavras com [`split`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split)
- pegar em todas as palavras e transformar num link com [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)
- juntar tudo de novo com [`join`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join)
- voltar a aplicar o novo texto como html no local certo

Exemplo:

```js
function aplicaLink(texto){
  return `<a href="https://translate.google.com/m/translate?ie=UTF8&sl=pt-BR&tl=en&q=#en/pt/${texto}">${texto}</a>`;
}

const divTexto = document.getElementById("div1");
divTexto.innerHTML = divTexto.innerHTML.split(' ').map(aplicaLink).join(' ');
```

```html
<div id="div1">The universe is to everyone</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

A minha solução passa por criar um link com a/as palavra/palavras selecionadas.

- getSelection() - Retorna um objeto Selection representando a parte do texto selecionada pelo usuário. Coloco isso em uma variável para concatenar ao link.

> Infelizmente aqui ao executar o exemplo, o link criado no topo do texto só abre se clicar com o direito do mouse e selecionar abrir em nova aba ou em nova janela.
>
> Mas no servidor abre clicando diretamente no link criado

**JavaScript**

```
   function showSelection() {
     document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML = document.getSelection();
     var variavel=document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML;
     if (variavel!=""){
        //o texto do link         
        document.getElementById("demo").text = "Traduzir texto selecionado";
        //o atributo href do link         
        document.getElementById("demo").setAttribute("href", "https://translate.google.com/m/translate?ie=UTF8&sl=pt-BR&tl=en&q=#en/pt/"+variavel);
     }
              
  }

  document.captureEvents(Event.MOUSEUP)

  document.onmouseup = showSelection
```

**HTML**

```
<a id='demo' target='_blank' href=''></a>    
    
<!-- daqui para baixo coloque seu HTML -->
```

Comment: Testei no `exemplo funcional` que deu e só abre se clicar com botão direito do mouse

Comment: @MiguelSilva, qual navegador?

Comment: Firefox 61.0.1 Quantum

Comment: @MiguelSilva, é verdade, muita coisa não funciona no firefox. Bad browser

Comment: Verdade e tem piorada a cada versão

Comment: Mas seu script me ajudou em outro projeto que pretendia copiar um texto selecionado para compartilhar, kkkk vlw mesmo

Comment: @MiguelSilva testei aqui com todos os navegadores, só o firefox deixou a desejar

Answer (score 0):

Você pode criar uma função javascript para abrir uma nova aba e recebe a palavra que deseja traduzir.

```
function abrePagina(palavra){
   window.open("https://translate.google.com/m/translate?ie=UTF8&sl=pt-BR&tl=en&q=#en/pt/"+palavra ,"_blank");  
}
```

Com a função é necessário adicionar o evento de click em cada palavra que deseja traduzir.